# Stopping a track (at a certain point) on Android

Tags: java, android, audio

I know you can `seekto()` with Mediaplayer, to start at a certain point.

But is there a way to make a track (the audio playing) stop at a certain point? Or would an if statement on a timer loop have to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make threat that will trigger [getCurrentPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition()).

When it will reach stop point, you have to stop MediaPlayer.

```
public void run() {
    while (mp != null && mPosition < mTotal) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500); // you can modify sleep time for better accuracy
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                if (mPosition == mYourStopPoint) { //remember to set mYourStopPoint
                    mp.stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Start this Thread in [onPreapared](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html) callback.

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer genericPlayer) {
    mTotal = mp.getDuration();
    new Thread(this).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem possible (correct me if I'm wrong) to do this with media player without resorting to seekto() in a timer loop. However you could try using an AudioTrack in conjunction with setting a notification marker:

[AudioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setNotificationMarkerPosition(int))

> Sets the position of the notification marker.

and overriding the playback position update listener [AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.OnPlaybackPositionUpdateListener.html)

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the playback head position of an AudioTrack has reached a notification marker or has increased by a certain period.

Comment: I'll try a timer loop, =]
I'm not much into effiency, but i'm guessing a timer loop is inefficient? :P :)

Comment: I'd say it was messier more than inefficient, probably wont slow app down noticeably.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, AudioTrack's position callbacks appear to be fairly seriously broken. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2563